# jQuery Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier success

Tags: jquery

For some reason I am having an issue with my `success` line I am getting the following error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` on this line why?

**Ajax:**

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "file.php",
      data: dataString,
      error: function(req, err){console.log(err);}
      success: function(response){Removed info}
});
```

I have tried `error: function(req, err){console.log(err);},` but this then gives me an error `parsererror` on the same line

Comment: can you provide fiddle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a comma at the end of the `error` line:

```
$.ajax({
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      url: "file.php",
      data: dataString,
      error: function(req, err){console.log(err);},
      success: function(response){Removed info}
});
```